# Is there a way to have multiple entry points in Create React App?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

I'm building a website using Create React App + React Router + Flask. The goal is for someone to be able to create forms and then make them public (similar to Google Forms) and view the results in their admin dashboard.

I'm trying to figure out how to give the forms a url that's accessible to anyone. Right now anyone with a form url must be routed through the home page since that's the apps entry point.

**Ideas:**

- Separate Create React Apps with Flask handling index routing to each
- Homepage URL with data stored in the home route that triggers separate routes
- Making forms in Flask

I'm trying to figure out a non hackish way to do this without ejecting. Is this possible? Maybe an SPA isn't the best choice but I didn't realize this would be a problem until now.  If anyone has any insight it'd be a huge help.